# Why is date format different on local PC and server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

We are developing **.NET Core 2.2** application. We noticed that date format is different on localhost than on the remote server.

- Localhost: `18. 06. 2020 15:12:53`
- Remote IIS server: `18.6.2020 15:12:53`

Date is displayed in `*.cshtml` using `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CreatedAt)`. Why is date format different although localhost and server use the same `Startup.cs` file? We want to have the format that the remote server produces on localhost as well.

**Startup.cs**:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...    
    services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultRequestCulture = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestCulture("sl-SI");
        options.SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("sl-SI") };
    });
    ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    ...
    app.UseRequestLocalization();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is the CreatedAt property in your model annotated? Try adding the [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]

Comment: No, it is not annotated. We have a huge application, adding `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]` to every single `DateTime` property is very time consuming. Is there another, more elegant solution?

Comment: String representation of date value depends on the localization settings of the server. You can check this settings from DateTime settings of the server and compare it with the same settings of local machine.

Comment: The easier way would be to change the locale options on the server machine then. Keep in mind that if its a distributed application, with servers in several places, you may come into issues.

Comment: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-date-and-time-formats-windows-10?amp

Comment: Force both server and your local machine to use the same Culture. That should solve it.

Comment: @MortenBork Do I achieve this by following steps in this link? https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-date-and-time-formats-windows-10?amp

Comment: @Mark dates have no format, they are binary values. Formats apply only when parsing text to dates, or creating strings from dates. Those formats depend on the user's culture. In desktop applications, that's the logged on user. In ASP.NET applications, the framework can detect the end user's locale from the `Accept-Language` header. You can disable culture detection if you want. Or you can store each user's preferences and use them during formatting.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos How do I disable culture detection? If I disable it, all users will have same date format and it will not depend on where we run the application from (localhost / remote ISS)?

Comment: @Mark
No you follow the solution provided in answer :)

Panagiotis Kanavos is correct that it doesn't solve the problem from external source, but your problem is from internal sources, so his objections are irrelevant. 

Hard-code the culture into your application that is running on a different OS, and the date-time default operations will follow the static- coded culture definition.

You don't want to alter the OS configuration, as it might affect other programs.

Comment: @Mark what *do* you want to do? Should the application use a single culture for all users? Or respect the end user's locale?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It should use a single culture for all users.

Comment: @MortenBork how would an internal application for a multinational Swedish company with offices in Denmark work with hard-coded formats?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This is not an issue in our case. We want to have the same format for all users.

Comment: They would all need to conform to the single hardcoded format. 

Simply choose which notation the system should pick as valid. Either 'DK-dk' or 'SE-se'

Doesn't matter which, pick one, and stick with it .

Comment: @Mark remove `app.UseRequestLocalization();` . Globalization and Localization is explained in [Globalization and localization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#implement-a-strategy-to-select-the-languageculture-for-each-request). The [Localization Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#localization-middleware) section explains how `UseResourceLocalization()` enables culture detection and localization

Comment: After that, the default thread cultures will be used, which depend on the web app account's locale. You can override this by setting the `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` and `DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture` settings

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar issue and below code solved my issue.

Apply `Culture` inside `Configure` like below.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    var cultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("sl-SI");
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;

    // your code
}
```

**Edit** I would recommend using `culture` value from the `appsettings.json`. This way in future you need to update culture you don't need new build. Just update `appsettings.json` and restart the server will work.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // Get Culture Info from appsettings and set Default culture for application.
    // If not found culture value from appsettings then use "sl-SI"
    var culture = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:Culture") ?? "sl-SI";
    var cultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(culture);
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;

    // your code
}
```

Comment: This isn't a solution, this just hard-codes a specific culture. You wouldn't even need that code if the OS's locale matched that culture. This won't work with web applications where you want to display data using the *end user's* localisation settings though. In fact, it will fail if ASP.NET's culture detection is on

Comment: ASP.NET in general can detect the *end user's* culture from the `Accept-Language` header. In other cases, it's preferable to store the desired culture/formats as a user preference, the way almost all forums do

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Thanks for your comments. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: Besides, unless culture detection is disabled, this code won't have any effect. The view will still use the detected culture

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I can remove culture detection by removing `app.UseRequestLocalization()`, right?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Thanks for sharing that it won't work in `view`. I guess in my case it worked because I was having web api. And was not passing `Accept-Language` header in requests either.